# How to resize first auto column in grid?

Tags: html, css, grid

I am trying to resize first column in grid searched on google but couldnt find the solution.
I can do it with css but want to learn how to resize repeated columns in grid.

I want first card to be `width: 50%;` and other two cards `width:25%;` and `width:25%;`

Here is my codes

```css
.slider-cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.slider-cards img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.slider-cards h3 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.slider-cards a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #0067b8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.slider-cards a:hover i {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="slider-cards">
      <div class="first">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/LZPVKq9/card1.png" alt="">
        <h3>The Conversation has reported</h3>
        <p>
COVID-19 has had a deeply unequal impact on UK society, affecting some communities substantially more than others.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Learn More <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="second">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/LZPVKq9/card1.png" alt="">
        <h3>The Conversation has reported</h3>
        <p>
COVID-19 has had a deeply unequal impact on UK society, affecting some communities substantially more than others.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Learn More <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="third">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/LZPVKq9/card1.png" alt="">
        <h3>The Conversation has reported</h3>
        <p>
COVID-19 has had a deeply unequal impact on UK society, affecting some communities substantially more than others.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Learn More <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

:

Comment: Set the width of each column `grid-template-columns: 50% 25% 25%;`

Comment: Solved with `.first { grid-column: 1 / span 2; }`.